# Why isn't there a CORS preflight check for POST requests?

Tags: http, post, https, cors, csrf

Let's say there's a hypothetical email site called `email.com`, and an evil site called `evil.com`. `email.com` sends the emails using POST requests.

A user that has session cookies of `email.com` saved on their computer visits `evil.com`, and  `evil.com` sends a http `POST` request to `email.com` that sends a scam email. As far as I understand the server would send the email from the user's account without making any checks, since the browser provided the session cookies with the request and preflight checks don't apply to `POST`, and then even if CORS doesn't share the response from `email.com` with `evil.com` because  it's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` doesn't include `evil.com` it wouldn't matter, because the email would already be sent.

I know this could be prevented by using for example a CSRF token, but why aren't preflight checks just implemented for `POST` requests too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You claim that

> preflight checks don't apply to `POST`

but that is incorrect: so-called [*simple requests*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) that happen to use the `POST` method don't get preflighted, but *non-simple* `POST` requests do get preflighted.

As an example, the following script run in the context of any Web origin other than `https://google.com` will trigger CORS preflight because, according to [the Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org) (which contains the de facto CORS specification), `X-Foo` is not a [*CORS-safelisted request header*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header):

```js
let opts = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "X-Foo": "foo"
  }
};
fetch("https://google.com", opts);
```

Alternatively, check out [this particular instance](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/?prefillForm=1&requestMethod=POST&requestUseCORS=1&requestSendCredentials=&preflightStatus=0&preflightAllowOrigin=&preflightAllowCredentials=&preflightAllowMethods=&preflightAllowHeaders=&responseStatus=200&responseAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&responseAllowCredentials=&responseExposeHeaders=&requestHeaderName=X-Foo&requestHeaderValue=foo) of [Jake Archibald](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake)'s [CORS playground](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/).

Besides, CORS preflight was never intended as a *general* defence mechanism against CSRF; this belief is a common misconception. Rather, preflight's purpose is to protect servers that predate the advent of browsers' support for cross-origin requests. The following [passage](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cors-for-developers/#getting-additional-send-permissions) of [*CORS for developers*](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cors-for-developers/) is enlightening:

> To protect legacy resources that may not understand CORS, you must first ask permission to expand your send privileges. This permission granting is done with a "preflight request".